# Creating an iPhone compatible website with iWeb

Tags: iphone

I'm starting a simple, static site with iWeb (latest version) and was wondering if there are any built-in or available resources for making the site compatible with mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://allaboutiweb.com/2009/07/iweb-sites-iphone-ready/) on making an iWeb site iPhone ready which states some of the things you can do, it seems like bad advise though.

Is there any reason why you are using iWeb for web development?  Making simple static websites can be quite easy and they allow you the flexibility to do some really cool stuff around responsive design and progressive enhancement, a lot of these notions are lost when you rely on a tool like iWeb to do the work for you.